# Fail to connect a uds client socket

Tags: sockets, client, connect, unix-socket

I'm new to unix domain sockets so i tried beej's code for client and server from: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/html/multi/unixsock.html

The server "works" but the client gives me an error when calling "connect" function. I'm getting: "Invalid argument" error.

any advice?

Answer (score 0):

try memset when you create a client socket

```
struct sockaddr_un sin;
memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was actually having the same problem with that tutorial, the problem is in:

```
len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
```

That assignment is missing the null character at the end of sun_path, so you just have to add one to the expression on the right:

```
len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family) + 1;
```

In my case the call to connect succeeded with that change.